# How can I add a created at for smart contract?

Tags: database, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I'm writing a smart contract for patient records. But the data will be in time-series data format. And I guess I should add created_at field for that. But I don't know exactly how to do this.

I'm pretty new at this job. Can you help me?

You can see part of the struct:

```
    struct Patient {
        string name;
        uint16 age;
        //max of uint16 is 4096
        //if we use uint8 the max is uint8
        string telephone;
        string homeAddress;
        uint64 birthday; //unix time
        string disease; //disease can be enum
        Gender gender;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `block.timestamp` keyword for have current block timestamp as seconds since unix epoch which your transaction is included.

More information about **block.timestamp** [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/units-and-global-variables.html#time-units).

You must to set your `createdAt` variable into a struct:

```
struct Patient {
  string name;
  uint16 age;
  //max of uint16 is 4096
  //if we use uint8 the max is uint8
  string telephone;
  string homeAddress;
  uint64 birthday; //unix time
  string disease; //disease can be enum
  Gender gender;
  // NOTE: createdAt variable
  uint createdAt
}
```

And then you must use this statement for set this variable:

```
[your_struct_variable] = block.timestamp;
```

Example of smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Hospital {

    enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE }

    struct Patient {
        string name;
        uint16 age;
        //max of uint16 is 4096
        //if we use uint8 the max is uint8
        string telephone;
        string homeAddress;
        uint64 birthday; //unix time
        string disease; //disease can be enum
        Gender gender;
        uint256 createdAt;
    }

    mapping(address => Patient) _patients;

    function setPatients() public {
        Patient memory _patient = Patient({
            name: "test",
            age: 50,
            telephone: "test",
            homeAddress: "test",
            birthday: 1010101010,
            disease: "test",
            gender: Gender.MALE,
            createdAt: block.timestamp            
        });
        _patients[msg.sender] = _patient;
    }

    function getPatient() external view returns(Patient memory) {
        return _patients[msg.sender];
    }

}
```